# Error in Swift while upload profile pic on quickblox

Tags: ios, swift, chat, quickblox

I am getting error while uploading profile image on quickblox.

Error is

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on this

```
let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(userImage, compression)!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the full documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation). Here are the reasons that this method might return nil.

> This function may return nil if the image has no data or if the
>   underlying CGImageRef contains data in an unsupported bitmap format.

It's also stated that the compression argument should be a CGFloat between 0.0 and 1.0. This value determines the compression of the image. 0.0 being the lowest quality (maximum compression). 1.0 being the highest quality (minimun compression).

If this doesn't fix your problem you might want to add in the context so we can see what mutates the *userImage* and *compression* variables

Comment: I have a in imageUrl and how I get name from that url ?

Comment: How I save image name?

Comment: Is the image on the internet or locally saved? Oops sorry. I read the explanation lemme just look it up

Comment: Image is saved on server

Comment: So you want to download the image?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to download the image. I found the way to download the image and it is working fine. Thanks for the help.